# CSS 3 rotate either 7 degrees or 14 degrees randomnly

Tags: css, rotation, rotatetransform

How can I make my css 3 div rotate either 7 degrees or 14 degrees randomnly, but if it is 14 degrees, it can't be 7 degrees and vice versa.

I have this code:

```
.foo {
background:#fefabc;7
-moz-transform: rotate(7deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
-o-transform: rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
transform: rotate(7deg);
box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px #333;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px #333;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px #333;
} `
```

So, how can I make this rotate 14 degrees randomnly so it is either 7 or 14 degrees.

I don't mind how to do this, as long as it is done.

Thanks, I have tried to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As CSS is not a dynamic language, you have to use javaScript to realize your goals. But you need to separate styles from javaScript Code. So the solution is that:

First you create two classes for both rotating 7 or 14 classes:

```
.deg7 {
/*This rotates 7 degree*/
} 

.deg14 {
/*This rotates 14 degree*/
}
```

Then, you load the elements you want to rotate and **add the class name randomly**

```
$('.rotating_element').each(function () {
  $(this).addClass(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'deg7' : 'deg14');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you can do this in just CSS, but if you also use JavaScript.

Something like this :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function rotate(){
  var deg;
  if(Math.random() * 2 > 1){
   deg= "7deg";
  }else{
   deg= "14deg";
  }
   document.getElementByClass('foo').style.rotate(deg);
}
```

Comment: Also with HTML5 if your looking for the future away from javaScript or PHP.